# MVC pattern, model class cant call one of the initilasers to be used to create an array

Tags: arrays, swift, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a Quiz app in Swift followed by the MVC design pattern. I am getting one error which is when I try to call the question variable to create an array called: "Questions" It cannot identify the question variable.

```
import UIKit

struct QuizModel{

    var question: String!
    var options: [String]!
    var answer: Int!



init(question:String, options:[String], answer:Int) {

    self.question = question
    self.options = options
    self.answer = answer

    }
}
```

this is my Quiz.model class

```
import UIKit

class QuizViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var QuestionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Options: [UIButton]!

    var Questions = QuizModel([question]()) // This gives an error:(

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        Questions = QuizModel(question: "What is my name?", options: ["AJ","Sazzad","Sami","Daniel"], answer: 2)
    }
```

If I don't use the mvc pattern it works but I want to learn how to use the MVC pattern I am new at this stuff if you can help me. I would appreciate it a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use proper variable naming convention(lowerCamelCase).

Since you define custom initializer and `Struct` is a value type, you will 
you will no longer have access to the `default initializer`.

You have to define `default initializer` explicitly to remove error.
ex -

```
init () {}
```

2. Your error will gone if you declare default initializer and declare it like this -

```
var questions = QuizModel()
```

Suggestions -
If QuizModel can be nil initially then declare it optional, then you don't need to define default initializer.

```
var questions: QuizModel?
```

or if it cannot be nil after first initializtion or first use.
you can go for implicitly optional variable.

```
var questions: QuizMode!
```

First think and analyze your problem and use all swift feature to improve your code.